# Installing php mongo driver on AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: php, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, php-mongodb

I am trying to deploy a php application on Elastic Beanstalk.  Everything is working fine except from my calls to the mongo driver.

My attempt to install it followed these steps (unsuccessfully):

1. SSH to Elastic Beanstalk instance.
2. `sudo yum install php-devel`  (for phpize)
3. `sudo pecl install mongo`
4. follow instructions to try command: `sudo echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php.ini` with
   failure.  error message is:

   `-bash: /etc/php.ini: Permission denied`

Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: The command `sudo pecl install mongo` will insert extension=mongo.so into php.ini, so you won't do it by yourself.

Comment: If you still want to insert it manually, you can try `sudo -s` and then `echo "extension=mongo.so" >> /etc/php.ini`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should not SSH into Elastic Beanstalk to install `php-devel` and `mongo`. Those settings will disappear when your EB environment scales in/out or server crash by accident.

Try to use [Configuration File](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html) to customize your EB Environment.

### Updated: add a configuration file example for PHP 5.4 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2013.09

1. Create an .ebextensions directory in the top-level of your source bundle.
2. Create a configuration file, `/your_app/.ebextensions/01install_mongo_driver.config`.

Type the following inside the configuration file `01install_mongo_driver.config` to install php mongodb driver.

```
commands:
  install_mongo_driver_command:
    command: pecl install mongo
```

Because PHP 5.4 on 64bit Amazon Linux 2013.09 AMI already contained `php-devel`, so you won't install it manually.

Comment: Hi @Dorian, I have added an example.

Comment: 02-mongodb:
    command: pecl install mongo
    test: "php -r \"exit(extension_loaded('mongo') ? 1 : 0);\""

Answer (score 5):

## Update for MongoDB on PHP 7 on Amazon Linux 2

```
files:
 "/etc/php.d/99mongo.ini" :
   mode: "000755"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      extension=mongo.so
commands:
  install_mongo_driver_command:
    command: sudo pecl7 install mongodb
    ignoreErrors: true
```

Above adds enables the extension on php.ini and installs mongodb for your PHP. The `ignore errors` prevents any error if installing a second time. (e.g. if your server crashes and has to reboot). This is to prevent an error that "mongodb is already installed"

Note: this file is stored in: /your_app_root/.ebextensions/mongo.config

Answer (score 4):

As fo today, the correct settings to install **mongodb** in the latest version of Amazon Linux 2 thru AWS Beanstalk is as follows, everything else fails for me. If you are unable to solve it, please do as I did and connect to the server a review the logs.

```
packages:
  rpm:
    php-pear: []
    php-devel: []
    gcc: []
files:
    "/etc/php.d/99mongo.ini":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            extension=mongo.so
commands:
    install_mongo_driver_command:
        command: sudo pecl install mongodb
        ignoreErrors: true
```