# Laravel with MongoDB in Elastic Beanstalk Composer Update Issue

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am trying to deploy Laravel application with MongoDB ext enabled for php in AWS Elastic Beanstalk.

I have the following configurations in `.ebextensions`

File: `01_install_mongo.config`

```
packages:
  rpm:
    php-pear: []
    php-devel: []
    gcc: []
files:
    "/etc/php.d/99mongo.ini":
        mode: "000755"
        owner: root
        group: root
        content: |
            extension=mongo.so
commands:
    install_mongo_driver_command:
        command: sudo pecl install mongodb
        ignoreErrors: true
```

I have even tried with `command: sudo pecl install mongodb-1.10`

File: `02_update_composer.config`

```
commands:
  01updateComposer:
    command: export COMPOSER_HOME=/root && /usr/bin/composer.phar self-update 2.1.11

option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: COMPOSER_HOME
    value: /root
```

But the build is constantly failing with following error:

```
> @php artisan package:discover --ansi
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'mongo.so' (tried: /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so.so (/usr/lib64/php/modules/mongo.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0
Script @php artisan package:discover --ansi handling the post-autoload-dump event returned with error code 1
```

Any idea what could be the problem?

**EDIT**

`cfn-init.log`

```
021-11-07 18:36:22,532 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-11-07 18:36:22,539 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-11-07 18:36:22,542 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-11-07 18:36:22,545 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_test_app
2021-11-07 18:36:22,545 [INFO] All RPMs were already installed
2021-11-07 18:37:20,444 [INFO] Command install_mongo_driver_command succeeded
2021-11-07 18:37:20,449 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_test_app
2021-11-07 18:37:23,357 [INFO] Command 01_update_composer succeeded
2021-11-07 18:37:23,361 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_test_app
2021-11-07 18:37:23,363 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-11-07 18:37:23,363 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2021-11-07 18:42:59,394 [INFO] -----------------------Starting build-----------------------
2021-11-07 18:42:59,401 [INFO] Running configSets: Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-11-07 18:42:59,404 [INFO] Running configSet Infra-EmbeddedPreBuild
2021-11-07 18:42:59,407 [INFO] Running config prebuild_0_test_app
2021-11-07 18:42:59,407 [INFO] All RPMs were already installed
2021-11-07 18:42:59,773 [ERROR] Command install_mongo_driver_command (sudo pecl install mongodb) failed
2021-11-07 18:42:59,773 [INFO] ignoreErrors set to true, continuing build
2021-11-07 18:42:59,778 [INFO] Running config prebuild_1_test_app
2021-11-07 18:43:02,716 [INFO] Command 01updateComposer succeeded
2021-11-07 18:43:02,721 [INFO] Running config prebuild_2_test_app
2021-11-07 18:43:02,725 [INFO] ConfigSets completed
2021-11-07 18:43:02,726 [INFO] -----------------------Build complete-----------------------
2
```

Upon `ignoreErrors: false`, the command throws this exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/aws/bin/cfn-init", line 176, in <module>
    worklog.build(metadata, configSets)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 135, in build
    Contractor(metadata).build(configSets, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 561, in build
    self.run_config(config, worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 573, in run_config
    CloudFormationCarpenter(config, self._auth_config).build(worklog)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/construction.py", line 273, in build
    self._config.commands)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cfnbootstrap/command_tool.py", line 127, in apply
    raise ToolError(u"Command %s failed" % name)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing php mongo driver on AWS Elastic Beanstalk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19914778/installing-php-mongo-driver-on-aws-elastic-beanstalk)

Comment: try removing the sudo in ` command: sudo pecl install mongodb`

Comment: @N69S For your first comment: I attempted that before, failed

Comment: @N69S For the second, still didn't work.

Comment: Shouldn't extension=mongo.so be extension=mongodb.so in the content part of mongo.ini

Comment: I have edited my question added `cfn-init.log` The build succeeded first then other builds are failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue by downgrading the platform to **PHP 7.4 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2/3.3.5**

For complete configuration anyone can use:

https://github.com/stescacom/elastic_beanstalk_laravel_mongo_config